# Criar um editor de texto que possa incluir imagem

Tags: javascript, html, css, blog

Olá! Estou fazendo um blog para um cliente que terá uma ferramenta para o adm cadastrar os textos.

Gostaria de um editor de texto que possa colocar imagem e gere um HTML, que nem este do Stack Overflow. Se puder este editor ser em HTML e JavaScript (jQuery)...

[image: editor Stack Overflow]

Comment: Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que você está procurando é um [editor WYSIWYG](https://tecnoblog.net/responde/o-que-e-um-editor-wysiwyg/), que é um acrônimo para *What You See Is What You Get*. Você pode buscar um que supra suas necessidades para implementar no CMS que você vai fazer para controlar os textos.